# how to boot from selected partition in Raspberry PI 3?

Tags: linux, multi-boot, raspberry-pi, bootloader, raspbian

I dont have extensive knowledge about bootloaders. I have some problem about updating the image in a SD card. I have a raspberry PI and i would like to make two partitions in the SD card, so that one partition holds the running image and other one has the backup image. If e.g. i would like to update the image, I do it in one partition and if it is successful then i switch to that partition, otherwise it rolls back to the previous running image. Now, how can i boot from the specific image according to my need? is there any good tutoiral or any good starting point about the bootloaders in linux environment/RaspberryPI 3? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning:** Playing with boot files is highly dangerous and can cause a non
bootable drive. Make sure to **backup files** from SD card before doing this.

**Procedure:**

- First boot from the current newly created bootable SD card
  because especially Raspbian does some initialization steps e.g. expanding the
  file system, editing boot files etc.
- There should be two partitions in SD card now, one `/boot` and other `/` (root).
  Then create the third partition (ext4). Copy all files recursively **with permissions**
  from second root partition to the newly created one.
- Now comes the tricky part. We have to instruct the kernel to mount our newly
  created partition as root. To do that, open `/boot/cmdline.txt` file in a text
  editor, replace this string `root=PARTUUID=6c586e13-02` to this `root=/dev/mmcblk0p3`.
  `mmcblk0p3` mean 3rd partition of 0th block [MultiMediaCard (MMC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard) aka. SD card.
  `root` defines the location of root file system.See [Raspberry Pi kernel command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/cmdline-txt.md)
  for further information.
- Optionally, edit the `/etc/fstab` file.

before

```
PARTUUID=6c586e13-02  /  ext4  defaults,noatime  0  1
```

after

```
/dev/mmcblk0p3  /  ext4  defaults,noatime  0  1
```

Comment: But, how i am gonna burn the image in this 3rd partition?As far as i know e.g. in balena while burning it creates a boot partition automatically? how i am gonna deal with it?

Comment: First do the installation procedure as usual with blank SD card. Then copy all the file from root partition (generally the 2nd one) to the 3rd one. I've already stated it in answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, Actually i want to use this procedure for the remote image updates. I would like to download the image and then burn it into 3rd partition and if the installation is done then on the next restart it boots from that partition. I were asking regarding this. do you have any idea about this one too? If you can help me, it would be really nice.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HassanHaroon I don't know about any remote setup. But it's possible to copy files from the IMG file to 3rd partition by mounting it in `/dev/loop` but it's beyond the scope of this Q&A.